# Как работают асинхронные вызовы?

Tags: асинхронность, callback

Как работают [асинхронные вызовы](https://habr.com/ru/post/216659/) на уровне приложения, ОС и железа.

Когда мы выполняем асинхронный вызов, например операция записи на диск, а ее результат обрабатываем в коллбэке, то:

1. Приложение обращается к ОС с запросом записи на диск.
2. ОС обращается к драйверу с просьбой записи на диск. Создается объект I/O Request Packet (IRP), он помечается как "выполняющийся".
3. Управление возвращается в приложение, выполняется следующая его команда. Та, что следовала за асинхронным вызовом.

Теперь обратный путь. Запись на диск завершена, и устройство уведомляет об этом процессор через прерывание:

1. срабатывает обработчик прерывания. Он берет IRP и помечает его как "завершенный"
2. Однако этот статус существует только на уровне операционной системы; процесс имеет собственное адресное пространство, и его тоже нужно уведомить. Поэтому ОС создает специальный-уровня-ядра объект асинхронного вызова процедуры (APC) и помещает его в очередь того потока, который владеет ДЕСКРИПТОРОМ.

Второй шаг мне и не ясен. Каким образом ОС поймет, что результат данного прерывания нужно передать в именно процесс моего приложения?

И как мое приложение получит результат обработки запроса? Если например асинхронным вызовом было не запись на диск, а запрос в БД - нужно же результат этого запроса передать как аргумент в мой коллбэк.

Comment: там же в следующем абзаце описывается что дальше происходит

Comment: можете объяснить своими словами? Не ясно, каким образом обработчик прерывания находит нужный IRP чтобы пометить его как завершенный, ведь на одно устройство могло прийти сразу несколько запросов, у каждого свой IRP. И самое главное - не ясно как находится нужный поток и адрес callback-функции, в который нужно передать результат?